# Note Taking Using Command Line History

Tags: command-line, bash

Is executing a line, beginning with a hash-tag, like `#something`, in a terminal, dangerous?

Something like:

```
usr@machine:~$ #something
```

Or in a multi-line manner:

```
usr@machine:~$ <<something
> 1
> 2
> 3
> something
usr@machine:~$
```

As I understand that's just a comment in bash; but wanted to be sure how it works in a terminal.

*Why?* The reason I do this; is that I want to use the command line history itself, for note-taking! I've set `HISTSIZE`, `HISTFILESIZE` and `HISTTIMEFORMAT` in `.bashrc` and it works just fine. This way, I can see my notes, alongside my commands, in a meaningful order, in time. I have some simple personal note-taking style that is getting parsed using a simple script.

Comment: As you self already stated it is a comment and stays a comment, nothing dangerous with that.

Comment: Thanks @Videonauth! I was not sure if the command line syntax is identical to that one of a bash script.

Comment: For your uses, the `script` command might be helpful too.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to get a newline recognized in a comment... that would make some comments no longer safe, but I don't suspect it's possible

Comment: @Xen2050 I've added the multiline comment too (I think; if that's the syntax; not sure - but works).

Comment: I was thinking of a single line that starts with `#` and *looks* like a comment, but contained some dangerous code later on, along the lines of your "Is a comment dangerous" first line. FYI, the `<<word` redirections are in `man bash` under Redirection -> Here Documents. It's not crystal clear (quoting any characters in word means something) but should be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, to make it official here is your answer.

As you already stated a comment line is a comment line, this wont even change if you enter one directly in terminal. This counts as well for lines beginning with `#!`, they are simply only comments for the shell/terminal when typed in by hand.

Another option could be to `echo` your comment directly into the `.bash_history' like this.

```
echo "# i am a comment to be saved" >> ~/.bash_history
```

Of course this would be a lot of typing each time, but this would even allow you to make multi-line comments with `echo -e`, here an example:

```
echo -e "# line 1 comment\n# line 2 comment" >> ~/.bash_history
```

Another option for making multi-line comments would be the following:

```
cat >> ~/.bash_history << "EOF"
># line 1 comment
># line 2 comment
>EOF
```

This way the lines with comments will get added and you end the input with typing `EOF`, thats as well pretty useful if you have systems where you have no editor at hand. You will keep adding lines till you input `EOF` which not gets recorded.

Comment: Thanks! Does that apply to `#!` too? Are there other things that one might be aware of?

Comment: @KavehShahbazian If you mean a shebang example `#!/bin/bash`? This is aswell in this case only a comment for the shell/terminal.

Comment: Sorry; I've added the multiline too. Would you please cover that too so this answer gets marked as answer? Thank;

Comment: @KavehShahbazian no proplem, covered that too now.